# OpenEJB cannot use javax.persistence.jtaDataSource

Tags: jpa, openejb

The following configuration is ok for WebLogic, but in OpenEJB it raises a error "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "AppDB" not found."

And if I removed the property javax.persistence.jtaDataSource, it works. And why set 2 duplicated datasource? Because it's a bug of Eclipselinks (see http://bugs.eclipse.org/246126)

```
<persistence-unit name="app1" transaction-type="JTA">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
  <jta-data-source>AppDB</jta-data-source>

  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="AppDB" />
  </properties>       
</persistence-unit>
```

The following is jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory
openejb.validation.output.level=VERBOSE
openejb.nobanner=false
jdbc/AppDB = new://Resource?type=DataSource
jdbc/AppDB.provider = org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider 
jdbc/AppDB.JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc/AppDB.JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx:xxxx
jdbc/AppDB.JtaManaged = false
jdbc/AppDB.UserName = xxxx
jdbc/AppDB.Password = xxxx
```

Because this is a jar packaged by other team, I cannot change the content but I still want to use it in my OpenEJB, any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all sure how EclipseLink processes the `javax.persistence.jtaDataSource` property.  I have to assume it's a JNDI lookup of some kind, but there's incredible significance in how they might do that.  If they prepend `java:comp/env/` for example, that significantly changes the semantics.

Maybe try overriding `javax.persistence.jtaDataSource` to use the OpenEJB global JNDI name for your datasource.  So in your `jndi.properties` file, add

```
app1.javax.persistence.jtaDataSource = openejb:Resource/jdbc/AppDB
```

Definitely let me know if that works.  Seems that might a good feature to add to OpenEJB even though the property is actually used by the JPA provider.  Fixing invalid JNDI names could be more than convenient.

On a side note, there should be a logging statement saying 'jdbc/AppDB.provider' is not a property supported by the datasource.  Probably best to delete that property.